# Moveit rviz plugin pr2 demo not working

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, pr2, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

I'm trying to use moveit on ros hydro, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. I installed it using the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-moveit-full

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-moveit-full-pr2
```

when launching `roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch` rviz starts well and it seems all ok, but then the MotionPlanning loads something like another pr2 perpendicular to the first and not completely mounted

[image: image description]

following the [tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Rviz_Plugin/Quick_Start) I changed some parameters like the Planning Scene Topic and finally the second pr2 disappears. But when I move around the start position and the goal position (making sure they are not in collision) and I click the 'plan' button nothing happen. If I try 'plan and execute' the second pr2 appears again and it seems like something is moving, but with the robot disassembled it's difficult to tell it!

Can someone help me? Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105261/moveit-rviz-plugin-pr2-demo-not-working/) by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 808 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like the same problem a number of others (including myself) are having with 32-bit Ubuntu installations of MoveIt.  You might want to add yourself to the list at https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_pr2/issues/25.  The only way I was able to move forward was to install 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 on another machine.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-11-27**:
Thank you very much for your fast answer!
Hope they will fix this problem in the future... For now I will try to install it on another machine with 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 (on which, luckily, I already have installed ros hydro). Do you suggest me to install moveit from debs or from source?

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-11-27**:
I would start with debs--they seem to be working for me so far.

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-11-27**:
Ok, thank you!